# Run a function/script in PHP and without affect the script flow

Tags: php, multithreading

I need to make a php script that execute another function (or another script) in background: When i call it, the flow of the script must continue even if the second script is not finished.

I found http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php (sleep function), but is not exactly what i need.

Some help?

Edit:

What i want to acomplish?
I need to make a change in my database. Then run a php script, but i need to make another change in my database 1 second (or whatever lapse) after i ran the php script.

Comment: Gearman, rabbitMQ, zeroMQ?

Comment: You might want to include more about what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Nibb I updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you apparently don't care about a response from the script you are calling.

And if your server allow...

You could call your script as if it was from a shell and say that it should discard output  with `"> /dev/null 2>/dev/null &"`...

```
shell_exec('php yourotherscript.php > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &');
```

Comment: `shell_exec` will block until the process completes so it does not satisfy the requirement *When i call it, the flow of the script must continue even if the second script is not finished*

Comment: No it won't block anything because of the `&`

Comment: I didn't catch the `&` in the command but it is still a good point that you should call out explicitly in your answer.